# Sliced numpy array does not own its data

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have to multiply two `numpy` arrays of different sizes (`a` and `b`), but I need to discard the first element of `b` before resizing.

What I see is that, if I use the full `b` array the resizing has no issues (but the result is not what I need, since it contains the first element of `b`). If I attempt to slice the first element off before applying `resize` I get a

```
ValueError: cannot resize this array: it does not own its data
```

Why does this happen, and how can I get around this in the most efficient way possible?

```
import numpy as np

# Some data
a = np.random.uniform(0., 1., 17)

# Works
b = np.array([56, 7, 343, 89, 234])
b.resize(a.shape)
d = b * a    

# Does not
b = np.array([56, 7, 343, 89, 234])[1:]
b.resize(a.shape)
d = b * a
```

Comment: Make a copy there with `.copy()` :  `...234])[1:].copy()` ?

Comment: I had the idea that `copy()` was not particularly efficient? This little block will be processed millions of times, so I need to make it as fast as possible. Also, why does the array not contain its data anymore after slicing?

Comment: If you care about performance, initialize a zero array and assign sliced array into it.

Comment: `Also, why does the array not contain its data anymore after slicing?` -Its a view into `b`, it doesn't have its own data. So, the in-place operation needed by resize won't work.

Comment: Is `a` normally (or always) larger than `b`?  So the the resized `b` is padded with 0s?,  `d` in that case will also be padded.

Comment: `a` will always be larger or equal to `b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to just do the multiplication for the terms that matter:

```
n = len(b)-1
d = np.zeros_like(a)
d[:n] = b[1:] * a[:n]
```

for:

```
In [628]: a.shape
Out[628]: (1000000,)
In [629]: b=np.arange(100)
```

this is 2x faster than (which time about the same)

```
b.resize(len(a)+1,); d = b[1:] * a
b1 = b[1:].copy(); b1.resize(len(a)); d = b1 * a
```

Relative timings can vary with the size of `b` and `a`.  While resize can be done in place, it probably will require a new data buffer, especially if it pads with a lot of zeros.

Comment: Indeed, this answer is much faster for large arrays, and a bit slower for smaller ones. Since my actual arrays are on the smaller side I'll use the `copy()` method, but this answer is the fastest for large arrays. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the other order? pad out `b` to one element longer `b.resize((len(a)+1,))`

then multiply `d = b[1:] * a`

```
b = np.array([56, 7, 343, 89, 234])
b.resize((len(a)+1,))
d = b[1:] * a
```

Comment: Do you have any idea if this approach is faster to the `copy()` method mentioned by Divakar?